# Duplicate Checker in Java

Tags: java

Ok, I'm new to this site but I do know that I'm not supposed to ask HW questions on here, but what I am asking is indeed HW BUT it has already been finished and submitted (and graded), I'm just here to hopefully get my program running with a better understanding:)

To prove that I've already completed it and not trying to pull a fast one, here's a link to the submission page:
http://i959.photobucket.com/albums/ae76/GoWxGaiA/HWDone_zps8ae79bf7.png

Now on the program...I'm supposed to be creating a program that checks for duplicate strings from the user input, and then output all the 'unique' strings in sorted order (ones that were not duplicates), and then output the 'non-unique' ones in sorted order right underneath the prior output.  My instructor told us that we had to use a 'Triple nested loop' which I assume is just a for loop inside a for loop inside a for loop...I get all the up to the point where I need to store the strings in an array in which case I cannot and have not found another way around.  What I submitted for this assignment is this:

```
package Homework2;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Homework2 {    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner stdin = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter a list of words:");
        String[] words = stdin.nextLine().split(" ");
        System.out.println(words.length);
        String[] array = new String[words.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
            if(words == words)           
                for (int j = 0; j < words.length; j++) {
                    array[j] = words;
                    System.out.println(array[j]);
                }

        }
    }
}
```

Again, I want to stress that I've already submitted this assignment and am just looking to properly complete this assignment to further my understanding.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: suspicious. `words == words` is always true.

Comment: Kind of odd to submit a solution that doesn't even compile

Comment: What's this words == words?

Comment: `array[j] = words;` doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

There are two obvious compile-time problems with this code:

`words == words` is always true. I guess you are trying to test wether there is a duplicate with this line, but this is not the way to do this.

`array[j] = words` tries to assign a String[] to a String variable.

This assignment is actually a little bit harder than it would seem at first glance. The trickiest part is printing the unique string in sorted order. The most practical solution is to use a linked list for this, which allows easy insertion in the middle of the list. I did assume that the use of Collections.sort() was not allowed. I guess it's possible that the use of LinkedList is also not allowed, but you didn't mention that in your question.

```
    String[] words = { "1", "4", "2", "4", "3", "1" };
    LinkedList<String> unique = new LinkedList<String>();
    LinkedList<String> duplicates = new LinkedList<String>();
    unique.add(words[0]);
    for (int i = 1; i < words.length; i++)
    {
        boolean found = false;
        for (String uniqueWord : unique)
        {
            if (words[i].equals(uniqueWord))
            {
                duplicates.add(words[i]);
                found = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (!found)
        {
            boolean added = false;
            for (int index = 0; index < unique.size(); index++)
            {
                if (words[i].compareTo(unique.get(index)) < 0)
                {
                    unique.add(index, words[i]);
                    added = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (!added)
                unique.addLast(words[i]);
        }
    }
    for (String word : unique)
        System.out.println(word);
    System.out.println("--");
    for (String word : duplicates)
        System.out.println(word);
```

Answer (score 0):

A rather simple solution that I like to use for this problem:

```
Set<String> used = new HashSet<>();

public boolean wasUsed(String s) {
    return used.add(s);
}

//using the method
if (wasUsed(yourString)) {
    // duplicate!
}
```

Sets contain only 1 of an element, and will return false when adding a duplicate. Makes things really easy for management.

As for your scenario, I would simply keep a separate `Set` of words, and remove them when you hit a duplicate.

You can read up more on [Java's Collections](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/) To learn about these helpful tools.